# Strange Grammar for Capital Letters

Tags: microsoft-word

Please write down these two sentences in MS Word 2013 x64 Win7

```
It is a Memory-Based CF. So, we use it.
It is a Memory-Based DB. So, we use it.
```

You see that only in the first line, it asks you to change `S` in `So` to `s` and not in the second! Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Same with Office 2010. The explanation for the grammar does not address it correctly either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because **cf.** [is an abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations#cite_ref-Maurer_3-1) meaning **compare** (used in texts to point the reader to another location in the text)

---

### Abbreviation

**cf** or **cf.**

1. [compare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compare), compare to
2. ([archaic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#archaic)) [confer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confer) (in the obsolete sense of compare) particularly in Webster's 1913.
3. cf. is sometimes mistakenly used to mean `see also'

<sub>from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cf#English)</sub>

Usage example (from [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/meaning-of-cf)):
*it refers to a discrete life form that has properties of mind (i.e. experience and character, **cf.** sentience)*

Comment: I was in the middle of giving that answer when I was alerted to yours! Note that **cf** is correctly spelled in lower-case, but I guess Word doesn't care about that. By the way, it's a transitive verb, not an adverb, but the English translation _compare with/to_ has to be rendered as a verb plus preposition.

Comment: @AFH I changed *adverb* to *abbreviation* since I couldn't find any references to *cf.* being described as an intransitive verb and abbreviation seemed more appropriate.